# getting instance id for nsstring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am trying to find out how to print instance id for known objects like NSString and NSNumber. When i try using it on any of those objects i just get content not the instance id.

Help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What do you call an instance id? Is it the address where the object is located?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"Pointer address: %p", myObject);
```